# In Remix - Solidity IDE, How to pass arguments?

Tags: solidity, remix

I'm studying smart contracts on solidity and I ran into a problem. Every time I try to create this contract, my arguments are not confirmed.

I expected a "OreOreCoin" to come out when I chose name, but instead I get an empty string.

[image]

and

[image]

This my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract OreOreCoin{
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    function OreOreCoin(uint256 _supply, string _name, string _symbol, uint8 
    _demicals){
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = _supply;
        name = _name;
        symbol = _symbol;
        decimals = _demicals;
        totalSupply = _supply;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value){
        if(balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;
        if(balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;

        Transfer(msg.sender,_to,_value);
    }
}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don’t quote the entire parameter list. In doing so, you're sending a single string parameter into the constructor that is converted to a `uint256` for `_supply` and the rest are defaulted. You can confirm this by looking at the details of the transaction in the Remix UI.

[image]

The parameter list should just be:

`10000,”OreOreCoin”,”oc”,0`